# Why am I getting a SQLSTATE[42000] error when I use bindings at the LIMIT section of mysql raw query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, binding

My query is quite complex, so I put here a simple example that ends with the same error:

```
DB::select("select * from Observation limit 0,?", array(10)))
```

The error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax...near ''10'' at line 1 (SQL: select * from Observation limit 0,10)

As you can see in the error message, the query build by the DB::select is a correct query. So, what am I losing here?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error, because you're using wrong syntax.

I think it's better way to use [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) to make your query more readable and avoid similar errors in future:

```
DB::table('Observation')->skip(0)->take(10)->get();
```

You can use raw queries, but you don't want to use them with simple queries:

```
$theLimit = 10;
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM Observation LIMIT 0, :thelimit"), array('thelimit' => $theLimit));
```

Comment: Well, in fact the query is far more complex than that. I have simplified it to focus on the error. I just wanted to use a raw query. I have done what you suggest in simpler query and I have no problems. I also have other bindings in raw queries and I have also no problem. The only situation in which I get this error is when I try to use a raw sql query and a binding in the LIMIT section.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Laravel 4.2. If I try your suggestion 

DB::select(DB::raw("select * from Observation limit 0,:thelimit"), array('thelimit'=>10))) I get a syntax error and it seems that :thelimit is not replaced.

"... near ''10'' at line 1 (SQL: select * from Observation limit 0,:thelimit)"

Comment: I checked that your last suggestion is not work due to the fact that I have the PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES config parameter set to true, because otherwise I was getting a mysql cache error from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query:

```
 $query = DB::table('table')
    ->select('item1')
    ->where('item2', '=', $a);

    if($limit !== null)
    {
         $query->limit($limit);   
    }

    $data = $query->get();
```